# why is isCustomResponse is not called the second time?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid

I define a Challenge Handler,

```
var AuthRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("AuthRealm");

AuthRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
    //returns true or false
};
```

once I  click the login button i send a request to the adapter:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
            "/adapters/AuthAdapter/getSecretData", WLResourceRequest.GET,
            30000);
resourceRequest.send().then(getSecretData_CallbackOK,
            getSecretData_CallbackFail);
```

However, after closing the app, re-launching and the login button is pressed again, the isCustomResponse is not called again. Why is it so?

I've checked that the isUserAuthenticated returns true, however it still doesn't call isCustomResponse:

```
WL.Client.updateUserInfo();

if (WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("AuthRealm")) {

}else{

}
```

Comment: Are you able to get the "secret data" when you press the button? (and what version of MobileFirst are you using?)

Comment: @NathanH Yes I'm able to get the secret data for both first and second time login. But I don't want the app to store the session or token. I want the user to login every single time (e.g. after they close the app).

Comment: @user1872384, Which MobileFirst release are you using? 6.3? 7.0? 7.1?

Comment: is that a new 7.1 app or an app you migrated to 7.1?

Comment: Also, in your `worklight.properties` look for a property called `mfp.session.independent` and tell us its value.

Comment: @IdanAdar It's a new app created using "Juno Service Release 2" and MFP version 7.1

Comment: @NathanH "mfp.session.independent=true"

Comment: I've changed the mfp.session.independent to false and mfp.attrStore.type to httpSession and it works! Currently I'm able to login 1st time, close the app and login again without issue. However what are the implications of changing these values in worklight.properties (e.g. can i still use jsonstore?)? Btw, I'm still not sure what's the proper way to write a logout function.

Comment: I am unable to write a full response right now. But this link should help in the meantime : https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to changing the project settings as was mentioned in the comments, to answer the remaining questions:

- There is no relation between the application session "state" to JSONStore. JSONStore is local to your app itself in the device and not to the network.
- You can invoke the logout function on application initialization, as a way to ensure that the client will be logged out once you have re-started the app in order to simulate the expected behavior by you. You will likely also want to [extend the splash screen duration](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/common-ui-controls/#splashscreen) while this action is done so the user experience will be better... the logout function needs to simply call WL.Client.logout (refer to the documentation for this).

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up @IdanAdar. However simply calling WL.Client.logout when logout button is pressed does not work, isCustomResponse is not called after logging out.   I used this code on click: <a href="#" ng-click="WL.Client.logout('AuthRealm', {onSuccess:WL.Client.reloadApp})">

Comment: No. I meant to call it in wlcommoninit to force a logout before attempting to login.